# Script tags - not linking (JS platform game)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working through the 'create a platform game' project from *Eloquent JavaScript* and have an issue with script tags.

In the book we're told to display our level using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css">

<script>
 var simpleLevel = new Level(simpleLevelPlan);
 var display = new DOMDisplay(document.body, simpleLevel);
</script>
```

I've tried adding this (together with an additional script tag for my platform.js file) into index.html but the browser is giving nothing back, not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the script that contains the code for  Level, simpleLevelPlan and so on? Have you included it *before* the script you show here?

Comment: This is where I'm getting a bit confused - I've tried adding this in the index.html file and the platform.js file and neither seems to have worked. I do have code for simpleLevel and for Level (both at the top of the platform.js file).

Comment: var simpleLevelPlan = [
  "                      ",
  "                      ",
  "  x              = x  ",
  "  x         o o    x  ",
  "  x @      xxxxx   x  ",
  "  xxxxx            x  ",
  "      x!!!!!!!!!!!!x  ",
  "      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ",
  "                      "
];

Comment: does the browser console show anything?

Comment: No, although if I console.log(simpleLevelPlan); it does show the array. I've tried adding the following into index.html but no joy:     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/platform.js">
      var simpleLevel = new Level(simpleLevelPlan);
      var display = new DOMDisplay(document.body, simpleLevel);
    </script>

Comment: The code you've written in your comment is wrong, you need two separate `script` tags for your platform.js and the inline JS, and the platform.js script tag needs to be before the other one.

Comment: Thanks KWeiss, you were right - shifting the script tags around did help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are inserting your scripts in the right order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        Here you should put your "included" scripts with <script src=...>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
    <script>
        Here you should put your first execution, if it needs the html page been completely loaded (as to use document.body).
    </script>
</html>
```

The scripts are being executed as they appear into the page. If you use `document`, you have to delay the execution until the whole page has been loaded: Either by putting your script at the end of the HTML, either by putting an initialization function within the HEAD, and call it from body onload:

```
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction(){...}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="return myFunction()">
        ...
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the external JavaScript file you need in a separate `<script>` tag *before* your inline script!